# Variable initialization - Python

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, initialization

I don't understand this problem

Why counter can be equal to 1 `i=1` (like in the code below)  or can be replaced by `i = 0` and the result is the same?

```
n = 4
sum = 0  # initialize sum
i = 1  # initialize counter
while i <= n:
    sum = sum + i
    i = i+1  # update counter
print("The sum is", sum)
```

Comment: The extra iteration with `i=0` doesn't add anything to sum.

Comment: You can get a clearer idea by running the code step by step from [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html)

Comment: why i = 0 and not i = 1 if the result is the same after I run the code?

Comment: sum + 0 = sum. Adding 0 does not change the result.

Comment: I am very good at math. :)  thank you Luk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# with added line numbers

1. while i < n: # modified this for simplicity.
2.     sum = sum + i
3.     i = i+1    # update counter
4. print("The sum is", sum)
```

Here is the execution to wrap your head around it.

```
# L1: i=1 n=4 sum=0
# L2: i=1 n=4 sum=1
# L3: i=2 n=4 sum=1
# L1: check i<n - True, 2 is less than 4
# L2: i=2 n=4 sum=3
# L3: i=3 n=4 sum=3
# L1: check i<n - True, 3 is less than 4
# L2: i=3 n=4 sum=6
# L3: i=4 n=4 sum=6
# L1: check i<n - False, 4 not less than 4 ; its equal. condition fail.
# L4: print 6
```

In case of starting from 0.

```
# L1: i=0 n=4 sum=0
# L2: i=0 n=4 sum=0 # see sum is 0+0
# L3: i=1 n=4 sum=0

# L1: check i<n - True, 1 is less than 4
# L2: i=1 n=4 sum=1
# L3: i=2 n=4 sum=1
# L1: check i<n - True, 2 is less than 4
# L2: i=2 n=4 sum=3
# L3: i=3 n=4 sum=3
# L1: check i<n - True, 3 is less than 4
# L2: i=3 n=4 sum=6
# L3: i=4 n=4 sum=6
# L1: check i<n - False, 4 not less than 4 ; its equal. condition fail.
# L4: print 6
```

When you contrast both; you did an extra iteration of work in the second case. But, that contributes nothing to the `sum`.

Hope this helps